# Quieter launches and crashes?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

While I quietly assemble and fly KSP rocketships, my wife quietly reads nearby, enjoying the gentle music and Wernher Von's ah-hah's.  Until I launch or crash-land one, whereupon the sudden noise makes her jump out of her chair and stomp out of the room.

By now I don't need an audio reminder that boosters have ignited or that the ship is becoming a cloud of debris.

**How can I quieten, mute, replace, or disable these two loud sounds?**

- Change a setting in a Unity config file?
- Delete or replace a few .wav's?
- Dual-boot into Linux and learn how to do PulseAudio filtering wizardry?
- Insert a hardware compressor-limiter between the PC's line out and the loudspeakers?
- Or resign myself to headphones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Audio section of the Settings menu, you can adjust the "Spacecraft" slider to change the volume of the engine firing. For turning down crash sounds, I'm not sure if that's the "Spacecraft" slider or the "Ambience" slider.

Comment: The "spacecraft" slider adjusts volume of both engines and crashes.  Also, reduce the value of Settings -> Audio -> Sound Normalizer -> Responsiveness to about 5 or 10.  Leave the Ambience setting unchanged.